# CSS Shape Animation with Tilt

Tags: jquery, ios, css-animations

I would like to make an animation that moves as a function of accelerometer values. (Basically, I would like to recreate something similar to the iOS Compass level, on an webpage.)

I understand how to make a CSS animation with keyframes, but because this is a continuous function I'm a bit confused how to formulate it. How can I set a shape animation as a function of a continuous value? (Using onDeviceMotion.)

Comment: When you say "continuous function" you mean a infinite css animation?

Comment: I meant a css animation that moves continuously with another variable, such as scroll or tilt. For example, I'd love to tie scale of a circle to accelerometer tilt values.